# Connecting multiple SMTP servers (Gsuite & Namecheap private mail server) in my EC2 instance (AWS) using Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, google-workspace, mail-server

I want to link my domain with 2 multiple mail servers, one is Gsuite which already works, but the other one is an SMTP Namecheap Private mail server that I have recently ordered, the problem is both requires MX DNS so am afraid that it will be corrupted, is there a safe way to connect both to my EC2 instance through Route 53 (AWS)?

Comment: Do you want to use them for sending emails, or receiving, or both?

Comment: SMTP Namecheap for sending and Gsuite for receiving

Comment: Well, `MX` records designate which are the receiving mail servers, so just keep Gsuite there as it was before.